# Get the last date from inside the loop

Tags: php

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<?php 
          for( $i = 1; $i <= $month_amortization; $i++ ) {
            $nextmonth = date('F d, Y', strtotime('+'.$i.' month'));

            $last = substr($i, -1, 1);
            switch($last)
            {
                case "1":
                $os = 'st';
                break;

                case "2":
                $os = 'nd';
                break;

                case "3":
                $os = 'rd';
                break;

                default:
                $os = 'th';
            }

          ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $nextmonth; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $i .$os . ' Monthly Amortization'; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo 'PHP '. number_format($monthly_amortization, 2); ?></td>
          </tr>
          <?php 
          }
          ?>
```

This displays dates. I want to get the last date from the loop. I tried echoing $nextmonth; but I'm getting only the date today. How can I get the last date from inside the loop? Any ideas? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You want to print the last date in each iteration of the loop?

Comment: @nicowernli yes I want to print the last date

Comment: Well it seems that @nicowernli mentiones not the same thing as you mention if I'm right ;) You loop through months, and all you want to echo is last month from loop right? If so whats wron now, because I've tested your code and it is working fine. If my speculations are wrong sorry then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$last_month = date('F d, Y', strtotime('+'.$month_amortization.' month'));
for( $i = 1; $i <= $month_amortization; $i++ ) {
    // your code here...
    ?><tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $last_month; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $i .$os . ' Monthly Amortization'; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo 'PHP '. number_format($monthly_amortization, 2); ?></td>
    </tr><?php 
}
```